# Nodejs Google Drive API Shareable link

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

For my Nodejs project I'm using Google drive API for file sharing. But the problem is, the URL I'm getting from API is not a shareable link. So I have to go to the drive and switch on the sharing. Is there a way to get the shareable link or switch on the sharing with the java script code? Please give me a solution for this.

Comment: Have you tried [inserting a permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert)? Adding a role:reader, type:anyone, withLink:true permission should make it shared via URL.

Comment: I'm using OAuth 2.0 user login. users access their G Drives. need to set the permission via API.

Comment: Try to use the [`alternateLink`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) for v2 or `webViewLink` for v3, it is a link that you can use and share to other people to access your file.

Comment: Thank you for the comments guys.

Answer (score 4):

The comments were very helpful indeed, this solution is for the v3 of Google Drive and the Google Doc v1. I was using `jwt` auth for Service Account and the `alternativeLink` using Drive v2 is not sharable.

**I'm assuming the auth process is known and complete. I'm writing the code in blocks so using `await`, promises, or callbacks is reader choice**

First, you need to create a document:

```
google.docs({version: 'v1', auth});
docs.documents.create({title: "Your Title"}, (error, response) => {
    if (error) return;
    //So now you have the documentId
    const {data: {documentId}} = response;
});
```

Now with the `documentId` we need to add a permission to the doc. The **key is to grant permission to anyone**. The doc explains `anyone` doesn't need an email or a user.

```
const resource = {"role": "reader", "type": "anyone"};
drive.permissions.create({fileId:documentId, resource: resource}, (error, result)=>{
    if (error) return;
    //If this work then we know the permission for public share has been created 
});
```

Now we are almost ready, we only need the URL. Gladly the sharable URL has a stable format, so we can compose it by our selves without the need for an extra request:

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/${documentId}}/view
```

Node.js Google Api changes quickly, in case of any confusion, I'm using `"googleapis": "^38.0.0",`